# WordprocessingDocument object: get filename property

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml

Is it possible to get the filename property of a WordProcessingDocument object? I know when you instantiate the object, you need to provide a path to the file, but I need to get that filename from the instantiated object.

```
Stream stream = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\username\Documents\DOCUMENT_NAME.docx", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);

WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(stream, false);
```

I want to get the **'DOCUMENT_NAME'** *String* from the *doc* object.

Comment: Is your file in XML? Why are you using `Wordprocessingdocument`?

Comment: I'm using `Wordprocessingdocument` object because I need to navigate through the XML nodes within the document XML, and retrieve specific nodes (text, comments, bookmarks, etc).

Comment: No, you can't retrieve the filename (neither a handler) from the WordProcessingDocument. You can't add the filepath where you need it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally prefer to use the office COM assemblies for communication between my application and any office document. it gives you more functionalities and it's quite easy to use.

Include the namespace `Microsoft.Office.Interoperability.Word` in your code to start with that.

Declare a `Word.Application` Object and use it to open, edit, extract data from your word document, including documents properties.

Leave `filestream` for handling large text files.

Comment: I'm using OpenXML because of the use of .docx files. The Interop API only works on .doc files.

Comment: The interop API works with many file formats. You can use the open method and specify the format (Open method: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.documents.open.aspx) File (File format enums: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.wdopenformat.aspx)

Comment: Yes, I was misleading in my previous comment. What I meant was that the Interop API does in fact work with several file formats but it does not work very well with the .docx format (e.g., it was created to be used with the .doc format), hence the use of the official OpenXML API (which is the one recommended for .docx and other Office xml zipped formats.
I've tried the Interop API, it doesn't suit all my needs. It's still a valid answer though, so thank you anyways.

Comment: I would suggest the following: Use Interop to get the file name. Copy the text of your docx into an XML object parser (for example Open XML).